# Isotope auto height fix

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have an issue with the layout, please find below for the image. How can I fix the layout for this? I want the height to be auto size, and the width to be (container width / 5)

Thanks in advance!

CSS

```
.element-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
    width:20%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.8);
-moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 5px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.8);
box-shadow:         2px 2px 5px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.8);
}
```

PHP Loop

```
<div class='element-item $folder' data-category='$folder'>
<div class='portfolio-thumb'>
<figure>
<a href='$file' class = 'fancybox' data-fancybox-group='$folder'><img class = 'lazy' data-original='$thumb'' /></a>
</figure>
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
     var $win = $(window),
        $con = $('.isotope'),
        $imgs = $("img.lazy"),
        scroll = $('body').scrollTop();

  var $width = $con.hasClass("no-space") ? 0 : 20;

  var $container = $con.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.element-item',
        // options...
        percentPosition: true,
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        columnWidth: $con.width() / 5,
        masonry: { columnWidth: $con.width() / 5 },
        filter: '.cables'
  });

  var event = $.Event( "click" );
```

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem and was able to solve it with the following code

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {

        // Run Masonry ( isotope )
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            stamp: '.item--static',
            percentPosition: true,
            resizesContainer: true,
            resizable: true,
        });
    });
```

Comment: The key of this method's success is to bind the `$container.isotope` function to the `load` event of `$(window)`. Otherwise isotope is not run when the page is loaded

Answer (score -1):

You need to use imagesloaded.js when you are loading images with Isotope so the layout occurs *after* all the images are loaded.
If you are using Isotope v2, you need to  download [imagesloaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/), load it in your page and then set up your code something like this :

```
 $con.imagesLoaded( function() {
 $con.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    // options...
    percentPosition: true,
    resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
    // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
    columnWidth: $con.width() / 5,
    masonry: { columnWidth: $con.width() / 5 },
    filter: '.cables'
 });
});
```